# move multiple files from multiple directories

Tags: macos, file, directory, command-line-interface

I need to move in Mac CLI multiple file from multiple different locations to one common target folder (consolidate them).
I have a parent folder, with 10 subdirectories in it, each subdirectory contains one txt file.
I need all txt files in the parent directory.
Sure I can do it manually, but I have the problem more often, often enough with more than 10 occurences.

My attempt so far

```
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec mv '{}' /Volumes/Extreme\ SSD/Math/Calculus/Calc +
```

I get this error

```
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Comment: Try `\;` instead of `+`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @avermaet.
Got in the meantime slightly different solution that worked:
find . -type f -iname "*.txt" | xargs -I {} mv {} "/Volumes/Extreme SSD/Math/Calculus/Calc" +